# Best connection node of sense pin for regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, voltage, rejection

I'm tring to get a high as PSSR as possible from my [ADP7142](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/ADP7142-1503407.pdf) LDO. Observe the following application circuit taken from page 1 of the datasheet:

[image]

The softstart (SS) pin is not available on my package and not needed in my design.
I'm wondering about the best connection for the sense pin, since I have multiple output capacitors. First a 2.2uf cap as specified by the datasheet, followed by a 100uf electrolythic:

[image]

I assume the reason for the separate connection of the sense pin is to measure the actual voltage present there instead of directly on the output of the LDO, which would probably not be equal.
Is the current connection the best, or would it be better to connect it to the pad of the 2.2uf cap?

Comment: Did you look at the TSOT example layout from the datasheet on page 21? It looks like you may have the wrong output cap.

Comment: Well I think the single cap is just the minimum.. I can't see any specified capacitance value for C2 in that example. However, page 6 specifies a 2.2 uf or greater output capacitor, for all package variants.